# Angular 2 – More helpful stack traces?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 2 a typical stack trace looks like this (see attached image)

[image]

Unfortunately none of these lines seem to be related to my code at all (using Typescript and lots of async / await). How can I get my *real* stack trace / line that threw an error?

(Yes, I also get lots of "Original Stack Trace" messages on the console, but they are similarly useless.

Comment: What about source maps? The fact that stack trace solely refers to `index.js` suggests that source maps aren't there.

Comment: Wouldn't a source map only map to a .ts file location? I don't mind looking at the JavaScript code. My problem is that none of the above is related to any of my code.

Comment: The purpose of source map is to map lines and columns in bundled js file to relevant lines and columns in source ts files. So the answer is likely 'that's because source map info was lost during bundling'.

Comment: Disagree. None of any of the lines above relate to any line in any code I wrote. My question is not about why `next()` or friends has a weird line number. My question is why the actual line that caused the error (in that case `behavior.value = x`) does not even remotely show up in that trace.

Comment: With proper source map you could figure out that the problem narrows down to Zone.js (the last entries in the stack) which just throws off the original stack trace. Addressing the issue properly gives you much higher chance to resolve it. I've seen this thing from Zone.js before and have no idea if this can be fixed at all.

Comment: The "actual" stack trace originated from a line where I assigned a variable `x` to the setter `value` in some reactive extensions Behavior object. Within that object the exception was thrown. Neither my line, nor the line of the Behavior object are shown; nor any other line that happened in between in the call stack. While I agree that source maps are nice, they will not add anything to this particular problem.

Comment: Again, the last entries in the stack belong to Zone.js. It isn't possible to say this from your screenshot or question details, but it is so. It is Zone.js that discards the rest of the stack. This is the fact that adds to this problem.

Comment: @left4bread did you ever figure this out? It's extremely annoying to be unable to find out where my application crashes. The only thing I get is a stack trace pointing to Zone.js similar to your screenshot.